# ETRS vs ETRF and EPSG

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg

[EPSG 25832 = ETRS89/UTM zone 32N](https://epsg.io/25832)…

Wouldn't it be more correct to call it ETR**F**89/UTM zone 32N and, if so, what's the equivalent EPSG code for ETRF2000/UTM zone 32N?

Comment: Search with code from http://www.epsg-registry.org/ and you'll see that ETRF89 / UTM zone 32N can be used as alternative name. I can't find EPSG codes for projected coordinate systems in ETRF2000 but there is a registered transformation method http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:coordinateOperation:EPSG::7942

Comment: On your 2nd question, ETRF2000 / UTM zone 32N, from what I remember from EPSG subcommittee meetings, latter ETRF/S realizations have been mainly been used academically or in geodetic govt agencies and not "publicly." Also, it's likely no one has asked for it but I'm not sure about that part. I don't feel confident enough to make this an answer. Disclosure: I'm on the EPSG subcommittee.

Comment: [EPSG 7791](https://epsg.io/7791) (and 7792 to 7795) is based on RDN2008 that, I think, is the Italy implementation of ITRF2000 (epoch 2008.0) but it is valid only for Italy

Answer (score 4):

Let me quote your link for you:

> Remarks: The distinction in usage between ETRF89 and ETRS89 is confused: although in principle conceptually different in practice both are used as synonyms.

Comment: Ok that the distinction in usage is confused...but it seems to me that they chose the less correct definition for the title..